# How to get rid of "brush is read-only" for painting textures or painting details in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to paint textures on my terrain I had created, but Unity isn't allowing me to do so and is showing a message saying that `"The brush is read-only"`. I tried looking for a solution online, but other people don't comment either because they don't know or it's not fixable.

The version of the Unity Editor I used for the project is Unity 2020.3.19f1.

Screenshot of the problem:

[image: Unity Editor showing the issue]

Comment: Do you have a Terrarin collider attached?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new material instead of using the default one ...?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you need to import your asset by it's name

```
com.unity.terrain-tools
```

[here's a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Me03zNkKy0) to help.

then install it that way from your project manager and it should sort out the ReadOnly problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

It was because I had set the opacity of the terrain paint brush to 0.2, which meant it wasn't being detected on the terrain object when I tried to paint the texture.